# toggle visibility within listview item in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to toggle visibility of a list view item by pressing on it.But after pressing on the same item twice it shows part of the layout which is supposed to hidden in the listview.

Onclick:

```
if (songsList.get(position).get("view").equals("0")) {

                        songsList.get(position).put("view,"1");
                    }else{

                        songsList.get(position).put("view,"0");
                    }
```

Within Adapter:

```
viewHolder.sno.setText( data.get(position).get("sno"));

        if ( data.get(position).get("view").equals("1")) {
            viewHolder.rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //viewHolder.desc.invalidate();
            //viewHolder.rel.invalidate();

            viewHolder.desc.postInvalidate();
            viewHolder.rel.postInvalidate();

        } else {
            viewHolder.desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.rel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //viewHolder.desc.invalidate();
            //viewHolder.rel.invalidate();

            viewHolder.desc.postInvalidate();
            viewHolder.rel.postInvalidate();
        }
```

Why does this happen.How can I fix it.I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Debug and see which unwanted part of code gets executed

Comment: I did that but its not showing anything also its more evident on a tab and not on mobile.How can I fix this?